# How can I show an array element that starts with a specific letter in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables, element

this is my array:

```
$aCars = array("BMW", "Audi", "Opel", "Mercedes", "Ford", "Fiat");
```

And I want to show only the array elements which start with the letter F.

But what is the most efficient method to do this, I have seen more questions like this, but I want to have a most efficient method to do this.

Comment: Foreach and test the first character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array_filter()` will *probably* be faster, since it is machine code, not interpreted PHP code.

```
$filteredCars = array_filter($aCars, function($car) {
    return $car[0] == 'F';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($aCars as $currentItem)
{
      if(strcmp(substr($currentItem, 0, 1),"F")==0)
      {
      //Do what you need here
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$aCars = ["BMW", "Audi", "Opel", "Mercedes", "Ford", "Fiat"];
foreach ($aCars as $model) {
    if ($model[0] == "F") {
        echo $model . " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient but short and simple. Match at the beginning of the string `^` the letter `F`.  The `/` are delimiters for the pattern that can be most any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character:

```
$result = preg_grep('/^F/', $aCars);
```

Comment: (Great, not seen that.)